WordPress Gallery thumbnail and single post issue after migrating to new host
After migrating to new host,i am facing a strange issue of Media image file's thumbnail while uploading to media gallery and also during editing or adding new blog post. The exact problem is as described below:
1- When i upload any new image to wordPress gallery, its thumbnail is not appearing in list mode, however in grid mode it is shown successfully.
2- I am unable to edit new image after uploading, even unable to add Alternative Text to it.
3- While writing new blog post, when i upload a new image it is shown blank with no image address or any other info.
4- I am also unable to add seo settings (like focus keyword, featured image, tags) to yoast interface after updating the article or publish it.
(the two images before and after migrating host is attached here for your kind reference)


In order to resolve the issue, i have taken the following steps:
1- Change generatepress theme to default wordpress theme.
2-Deactived all plugins and activate them one by one.
3-Checked the theme file for any malicious code snippet.
4- Check the folder and image permission in cpanel and found it as 755 and 644 for folder and image file.
But, the problem is still there.
So kindly give suggestions to resolve it.
